# How to use if/else statement in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

[image: Picture]
First look at the picture. Now if the edit link is present, I have to perform some steps, if edit link is not present, I have to perform different steps. How can I do this in Selenium IDE.

Comment: I don't really like to use the plug-ins to allow if-else statements. I usually suggest to people that they think of moving away from IDE if they need that type of ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is example of if else  on ide . On ide you will see three columns  command , target and value

```
Command |Target | value
store   | true  | var1
if      | storedVars.var1
echo    | I am in the if
else
echo    | I am in the else
endIf
```

If you have any further question than feel free to contact here

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:

[image: gotoIfSample]

I provided comments for you to easily understand. 
I've been using the `gotoIf` command as an alternative for the if-else statement for a while. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: I got `[error] Unknown command: 'gotoIf'` in Selenium IDE 2.9.1

Comment: You need to have SeLite SelBlocks Global installed in order for it to work.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/selite-selblocks-global/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no 'if' command in Selenium IDE. However, you're lucky there sure is 'gotoIf'!

This is how you can use 'gotoIf' command to perform the required steps if the 'Edit' link is present:

[Checking a condition using 'gotoIf'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlBAu.png)

Hope this helps. Do let me know in case of any questions.

Comment: this answer would be better if you provided an example that specifically answers the question, instead of just a link (which might die one day)

Comment: I apologize for any inconvenience. However, if you care to open the link, you'll find out that it is simply an image (screenshot) of the very specific example that I had written in Selenium IDE.